# how to stop unknown running docker containers

Tags: docker, containers

I have docker installed on my mac and when I do `docker info` I see this information:

```
Containers: 9
 Running: 8
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 5
```

But, when I run `docker container ls -a` or `docker ps -a` Then I see nothing running there.

I can see the 5 running Images when I do this: `docker images -a` ,

```
REPOSITORY                                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver-amd64            v1.10.11            e851a7aeb6e8        3 months ago        228MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager-amd64   v1.10.11            978cfa2028bf        3 months ago        151MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler-amd64            v1.10.11            d2c751d562c6        3 months ago        51.2MB
k8s.gcr.io/etcd-amd64                      3.1.12              52920ad46f5b        11 months ago       193MB
k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64                     3.1                 da86e6ba6ca1        14 months ago       742kB
```

But I'm unable to delete them.

I tried doing this: `docker rmi <image_id>` or even this: `docker rmi $(docker images -aq)`

both gave errors like this:

`Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete <image_id> (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container <container_id>`

When I try to kill one of these "running" container IDs, like this: `docker kill <container_id>`, I get the error:

`Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: <container_id>: Container <long_container_id> is not running`

Or, if I do `docker stop <container_id>` then I just get back the container ID meaning the container is already stopped I guess? and yet even After that, trying to remove the images, gives the same error.

So, how do I get rid of these running "ghost" containers and images?

Comment: Are you using Docker for Mac or Docker for Windows?  If so, do you have Kubernetes enabled in the Docker preferences?

Comment: it is docker for Mac, and yes, Kubernetes is turned on, but it just shows `Kubernetes is starting`

Comment: I’m guessing you do not have “Show system containers (advanced)” checked.

Comment: yes, that is correct, but since the docker is stuck on `Kubernetes is starting`, these settings are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need the container, you can remove the container the same way you would the image

```
docker rm <container_id>
```

then after that you should have better luck removing the image

```
docker rmi <image_id>
```

or as you had to remove all images

```
docker rmi $(docker images -qa)
```